# Check if an image is valid(corrupted) javaCV

Tags: java, image, opencv

I have a list of directories and sub-directories with images. I am using JavaCV in order to read all images and by using cvShowImage to imshow those images. I am reading the files using listFilesForFolder function.  My problem is that some images in those folders are not valid(corrupted). Thus I am getting Opencv exception errors:

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer () in cvReleaseImage, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2983
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2983: error: (-27)  in function cvReleaseImage
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage(Native Method)
```

How can I check in my code if an image is valid(corrupted) or not in order to continue the for-loop in which I read all my images? I am using the following function in order to read images:

```
public IplImage openImage(String name) {


    IplImage img = cvLoadImage(name);
    cvShowImage("hello", img);
    cvWaitKey();
    cvReleaseImage(img);
    return img;
}
```

When I run the program I got issues in cvReleaseImage(img) line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check if the image is `null` or not.

```
public IplImage openImage(String name) {

    IplImage img = cvLoadImage(name);
    if(img != null)
    {
        cvShowImage("hello", img);
        cvWaitKey();
        cvReleaseImage(img);
    }
    return img;
}
```

Comment: I want to return IplImage image in case of img is valid. How can I exit without returning anything and continue the for-loop in the main function?